# Proper placement of "e.g."

Tags: commas, abbreviations

I am a little bit confused after I found out that "e.g." is followed by a comma in American English. My confusion stems from the correct placement of this abbreviation. Consider the following sentence:

> Usually, these entities are both represented in the source language,
>   e.g., as modules or top-level declarations, and easy to distinguish
>   from each other by the user and the compiler, e.g., as separate
>   files or directories.

When reading this sentence, I stumble upon the commas after the "e.g."s. I could understand it if the sentence was:

> Usually, these entities are both represented in the source language,
>   as, e.g., modules or top-level declarations, and easy to distinguish
>   from each other by the user and the compiler, as, e.g., separate
>   files or directories.

The second version reads somewhat slower, there is more emphasis on the ".e.g." as I would like and the meaning of the second "as" might be confused to relate to the "compiler".

Is the first form correct? If so, I wonder what purpose the commas serve? Is the second version different in meaning from the first, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: "as, e.g.," is very hard to parse for me. I wouldn't recommend writing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The first form is correct (but read on). As you probably know, **["e.g."](http://www.dictionary.com/e/whats-the-difference-between-ie-and-eg/)** is an abbreviation of the Latin ***exempli gratia,*** which means “for the sake of example” or more simply, "for example." By [convention](http://www.writingsimplified.com/2009/09/how-to-use-ie-and-eg.html), there is no space between "e." and "g.," and "e.g." is followed by a comma in American English.

[This article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/comma-after-i-e-and-e-g/) notes,

> The Chicago Manual of Style states that i.e. and e.g. should be “confined to parentheses and notes and followed by a comma.”
>
> The AP [Associated Press] Stylebook, whose “punctuation-pitch” leans generally to the side of “the fewer commas the better,” is pro-comma when it comes to i.e. and e.g. According to AP, both abbreviations are “always followed by a comma.”

The same article points out,

> The *Penguin Writer’s Manual* (British) shows both *i.e.* and *e.g.* without a following comma.

and offers the following advice:

> As with so many matters of punctuation, the writer’s best practice is to choose a style reference and follow its recommendations.

Many writers choose to avoid its use and instead write plainly, "for example."

You may also find the answers to [**this EL&U post**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/should-i-always-use-a-comma-after-e-g-or-i-e) useful.

Comment: These are parentheticals (asides) within parentheticals (such as appositions).  Since their goal is brevity, why not assume some comma[s] within the abbreviation?