# What are some commonly used expressions used in English, that originate from latin or else?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

I am not sure what I am specifically asking for, 
Basically I'd like to get a list of these special expressions, from you, because I can't seem to find one.  NOT ASKING ABOUT THE USAGE of these that I mentioned here, **I want to get a list of the expressions that are used in English, despite their lack of grammatical sense, (because they're not English)**

e.g

i.e,

in explicit, or other stuff like that - that has not much of a direct meaning, but has some symbolic or historical values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I always use a comma after "e.g." or "i.e."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/should-i-always-use-a-comma-after-e-g-or-i-e)

Comment: @rajah9 I think they're asking for other Latin abbreviations, not necessarily usage tips on e.g. and i.e.?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. *I.e.* stands for *id est* in Latin, meaning “that is." *E.g.* stands for *exempli gratia* in Latin, meaning “for example”.

Comment: Agreed, @Jaekelopterus, but we also ask for some basic research from the OP.

Comment: @rajah9 I am not asking about what these two mean, I gave them as an example of expressions that are used in a manner that the expressions I want to get a list of, but can't better express them than by giving these reference examples.

Comment: How about "quid pro quo"?  (I have yet to figure out what calamari has to do with Trump's impeachment.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common abbreviations in English which are of Latin origin include:

1. etc (Et cetera)
2. AD (anno domini)
3. a.i. (ad interim)
4. et al (et alii)
5. per cent (per centum)
6. vs (versus)
7. am (ante meridiem)
8. pm (post meridiem)
9. N.B. (nota bene)

See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations), [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases), or [this one](https://www.translationdirectory.com/glossaries/glossary138.htm) for more.

Comment: thanks for the links, that's what I asked for!