# What's the correct punctuation of "i.e." and "e.g."?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, end-punctuation

I'm confused about how to correctly punctuate these two. Can someone elaborate?

Here's an example:

> She said that the pain was 100/10 – **i.e.** above the top of the scale.
>
> She said that the pain was 100/10 – **i.e.,** above the top of the scale.

I think that the first example is correct, but is it?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I always use a comma after "e.g." or "i.e."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/should-i-always-use-a-comma-after-e-g-or-i-e)

Comment: Excellent, yes, understood. Thank you.